# Confusion regarding javascript object

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this work?

```
function displayValue(a,b){
     this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    $('p').text(a + " " + b);
}

var display = new displayValue();
display('1','2');
```

Why does this work even without the 'new' keyword?

```
function displayValue(a,b){
     this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    $('p').text(a + " " + b);
}

var display =  displayValue('1','one');
```

With the new keyword, am I created an object? How can I alter the displayValue's property?

Comment: You're running it twice, seeing whos naughty or nice, but the function doesn't return a function, and you're not passing arguments in the first call, just the second call, who isn't really calling anything as the first call returns the object, so santa clause isn't coming tonight.

Answer (score 2):

> why does this work even without the 'new' keyword?

Your first example *doesn't* work. You'll get `"undefined undefined"` in your paragraph element(s), and an error in your console when you call `display`, since `display` isn't a function.

> If with the new keyword, am I created [sic] an object?

Yes. The `new` operator creates a new object and then calls the constructor function so that `this`, within the function, is a reference to the new object.

In your second case, where you don't use `new`, within the call to `displayValue` `this` is actually a reference to the `window` object, which is the global object in browsers. (If you were using JavaScript's new "strict" mode, `this` would be `undefined` and you'd get an error doing `this.a = a;`.)

> How to alter the displayValue's property?

I'm afraid I don't understand that question. If your goal is to have a constructor function that returns an object that has `a` and `b` properties, and that you can then use to update the text of a paragraph using those properties, it might look like this:

```
// Defining it
function DisplayValue(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
DisplayValue.prototype.display = function() {
    $("p").text(this.a + " " + this.b);
};

// Using it
var d = new DisplayValue(1, 2);
d.display(); // Changes all paragraphs to "1 2"
d.a = "A";
d.b = "B";
d.display(); // Changes all paragraphs to "A B"
```

Comment: so the second code without 'new' is actually not a good practice? because I saw many programmer do that.

Comment: @user3057928: It depends entirely on what you're trying to do. You should only use `this` within a function if it's a constructor function, or a function that you know will be called with `this` set to having a specific meaning. (The event handlers attached to DOM elements with `addEventListener` or libraries like jQuery, for instance, get called with `this` referring to the element.)

Answer (score 0):

functions in JavaScript has two different roles:

1- they serve as a function as you have used it in your second block.
2- they can be used as a Class to make objects, as you have used it in your first block.

the same function would be serve as different means, for instance:

```
var display = new displayValue();
```

means you want to create a Object based on your Class(the function), cause you have used `new` keyword and also the `display` as a result of `var display = new displayValue();` is not a function it is a javascript object and you can get your props like this : `display.a` or `display.b`. but when use it as a method like:

```
displayValue('1','one');
```

this way, it is just a function to be called and the most important point here is `this` in this function would point to the function's container object which is mostly is your top level class or `window` object.
in your function:
    function displayValue(a,b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        $('p').text(a + " " + b);
    }
when you do `this.a = a;`, mostly it means you want to use it as a Class or as a method in a the top level class, for instance:

```
function Display(){
    this.displayValue=function displayValue(a,b){
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       $('p').text(a + " " + b);
    }
}
```

or

```
function Display(){
   //the constructor
}
Display.prototype.displayValue = function displayValue(a,b){
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
   $('p').text(a + " " + b);
};
```

in this example if you try `var obj = new Display();`, the `this` keyword in `displayValue` function would point to the current instance of `Display` which is `obj`.